# Enabling connection checker and statements tracker on JBoss 5 app server

Tags: java, jboss, datasource

I am using JBoss datasource (`<local-tx-datasource>`) on IBM DB2 9.7 database. The connectivity works fine.

However, I have tried enabling the `<track-statements>`, `<valid-connection-checker>`, and `<check-valid-connection-sql>` properties, but how do I know they are working? I get no errors or warnings on server console when using the datasource, but I also don't get any enhanced logging.

Below is a slightly modified version of what I am using. I have tried various property combinations. Below I have commented out the check-valid-connection-sql property, but enabled the valid, stale and exception sorter properties. I am using JBoss5 and I wonder if it has an impact.

I have tried e.g. to remove a hibernate session close statement in a finally clause, but nothing is logged. It just seems that the additional properties below are not enabled for some reason, or at least they are not logged in the JBoss server.log log file.

```
<datasources>
<local-tx-datasource>
<jndi-name>[jndiname]</jndi-name>
<connection-url>jdbc:db2://[ip]:[port]/[dbname]</connection-url>
<driver-class>com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver</driver-class>
<user-name>[user]</user-name>
<password>[password]</password>
<min-pool-size>10</min-pool-size>
<valid-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.db2.DB2ValidConnectionChecker"></valid-connection-checker>
<stale-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.db2.DB2StaleConnectionChecker"></stale-connection-checker>
<exception-sorter class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.db2.DB2ExceptionSorter"/>
<track-statements>true</track-statements>
  <metadata>
     <type-mapping>DB2</type-mapping>
  </metadata>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have `valid-connection-checker-class-name`, `check-valid-connection-sql`, and `validate-on-match` (set to true by default) properly configured then you can test that it works by manually performing an outage on your database server and see if JBoss reconnects and refreshes the datasource pool with valid connections.

I would not recommend keeping `track-statements` enabled in production. It is mainly a debug feature to track whether you are not closing statements and resultSets properly in your code. Turn it on in dev or test servers to validate that you are properly closing them (e.g. close them in a finally block). You can test it by validating messages like "Closing a result set you left open! Please close it yourself." in server log.

Comment: Hi CooLBeans. I edited my initial question to include my xml file. I tried "forgetting" to close my hibernate session but nothing is logged, at least not in server.log file within JBoss.

Comment: Hi - I said connection, but actually meant statements and result sets. I edited my post to correct that. Try not to close statements and result sets and observe jboss server log messages.